# Testing environment in Hyperledger-Fabric through single node ( NOOPS )

Tags: unit-testing, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am running single peer for testing chaincode. where I don't need to authenticate any trasaction so I am using NOOPS Consensus. Should i have to use any channel.?

Can anyone help me to understand this.?

Answer (score 0):

If these assumptions are correct, you are using Hyperledger fabric V1.0 Alpha or Alpha 2, and using the solo ordering service, then yes use a channel. However NOOPS is throwing me a little since I've not really heard that since v.6. In that case, there is no concept of a channel.